# Gmail API User.Message properties not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth, google-apis-explorer

Looking at the list of properties here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages
You can see all of the properties. However, currently for me, only Id and Thread ID is working. Is it user error or something wrong with the API?

```
   function listMessages() {
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'maxResults': 1000,
      'userId': 'me',
      'format': 'full',

    }).then(function(response) {
      appendPre('Files:');
      var messages = response.result.messages;
      if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
          var message = messages[i];
          appendPre(message.threadId + ' (' + message.snippet + ')');
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Any help with getting the name of the email printed would be appreciated. I can only print out message.ThreadID and message.ID, with everything else (such as message.snippet) printed out as undefined.

This is what happens when the ID and snippet are printed out: The ID prints out but nothing else, I've tried this with a few other varables as well, all of them but ID and threadID prints out as undefined.
[image: .]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try adding `format=RAW` in your [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) request.

As also mentioned in [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages),

> The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string. Returned in `messages.get` and `drafts.get` responses when the `format=RAW` parameter is supplied.

Comment: Ok thanks! Also, is there a way to have two client_ids in the same script? If so, how?